# Ruby - How to change an instance variable in various objects using map method

Tags: ruby

Lets have a class like this:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :var_1, :var_2, :var_3

  def initialize(var_1, var_2, var_3)
    @var_1 = var_1
    @var_2 = var_2
    @var_3 = var_3
  end
end
```

and now we create some objects:

```
a = Foo.new("c", 1, "d")
b = Foo.new("e", 2, "f")
c = Foo.new("g", 3, "h")
```

then we make an array with the new created objects:

```
array = [a, b, c]
```

And here where I'm stuck, I want to add a new value to an specific instance variable from object.

**Example:**

I try to change `var_2` increased by one, but I don't know how to call or assign it to the instance variable `var_2`:

```
newArray = array.map { |x|

   x.var_1 + 1 # assign the new value to the instance variable 'var_2'
}

def showArray(array)

  array.each do | var |
    puts "Var 1: #{var.var_1} | Var 2: #{var.var_2} | Var 3: #{var.var_3}"
  end
end

showArray(newArray)

# desired output:
# => Var 1: c |  Var 2: 2 |  Var 3: d
# => Var 1: e |  Var 2: 3 |  Var 3: f
# => Var 1: g |  Var 2: 4 |  Var 3: h
```

I have to use the map method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you have is that your `map` function is returning the value of `x.var_1 + 1` which is an `Integer`.  When you loop back over it, you're looping over `Integer`s not `Foo` objects.

You almost have it, you just need to use an assignment operator such as `+=`to `assign` `val_2` to itself `+ 1` like this:

```
newArray = array.map { |x|
   x.var_2 += 1 
   x
}

def showArray(array)

  array.each do | var |
    puts "Var 1: #{var.var_1} | Var 2: #{var.var_2} | Var 3: #{var.var_3}"
  end
end

showArray(newArray)
```

output:

```
Var 1: c | Var 2: 2 | Var 3: d
Var 1: e | Var 2: 3 | Var 3: f
Var 1: g | Var 2: 4 | Var 3: h
```